# Some information about Accept Header when I have an URL that end with a specific extension (like .xml)

Tags: java, php, http, header, http-headers

I have a question about Accept HTTP Header.

If I have a link ending with a specific extension, like in this case where my URL end with **.xml**:

```
<a id="writeXmlExt" class="writeXmlLink" href="<c:url value="/messageconverters/xml.xml" />">Write XML via ".xml"</a>
```

I would know if using URL that ending with an extension I am automatically setting the Accept header value related to the extension used.

For example, in the previous link is auomatically setted the Accept Header to the value: **application/xml** ?

Thank you

Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Accept header field isn't changed based on the href.

Comment: what do you exactly mean?
If the URL of my href end with .xml the browser don't set automatically the Accept Header value?